# How do I make a chat system with php and JQuery

Tags: php, jquery

I made a table called names which gets updated each time a user logins and logs out. I need help in making a column which display the names of all the people whose `status` in the table `names` is set to `YES`, and when the user clicks on his name, the chat box appears and they chat. I have already made the chat box with its coding, all I need help in is showing the names of people online. I will prefer doing this by php and JQuery **if possible** but if you have a better way, please tell me.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

This will help you .

http://tutorialzine.com/2010/10/ajax-web-chat-php-mysql/